# Managing the lifecycle of multiple Flux with spring-data-mongodb-reactive

Tags: mongodb, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I have a data service and I am seriously considering switching to a reactive model.  This is a federated query engine that can resolve data for queries by invoking one or more "resolver" implementations, depending on the query type.

If I switch to `spring-data-mongodb-reactive`, then each of these implementations would have to create a number of `Flux` instances for:

1. the queries for different parts of the information
2. querying all databases for each query from #1

***Note***: I don't want to combine every `Flux` because being able to keep the queries for #1 above separate make the final processing much easier.  Combining each "part" query for all federated databases would be fine, but I have to keep the data for each "part" separate.  I hope that makes sense.

Explaining the full workflow is out of the scope of this post, but I am wondering how I can create any number of `Flux` instances, and subscribe to them to get them started, but then wait until they all complete before proceeding with the processing of the fully-retrieved data across all federated sources.  In Java, I am looking for something that is analogous to a `CompletableFuture.allOf()`.

Am I even close to being on the right track if I do something like this:

```
public class ReactiveDataService {
    private static final Supplier<Example<String>> example1 = () -> Example.of("Example 1");
    private static final Supplier<Example<String>> example2 = () -> Example.of("Example 2");
    private static final Supplier<Example<String>> example3 = () -> Example.of("Example 3");
    private static final Supplier<Example<String>> example4 = () -> Example.of("Example 4");
    private static final Supplier<Example<String>> example5 = () -> Example.of("Example 5");
    private final Collection<ReactiveMongoRepository<String, String>> repositories;

    public ReactiveDataService(Collection<ReactiveMongoRepository<String, String>> repositories) {
        this.repositories = repositories;
    }

    private void processFluxes(final Flux<String> flux1, final Flux<String> flux2, final Flux<String> flux3,
                               final Flux<String> flux4, final Flux<String> flux5) {
        // Call service to process flux stuff
    }

    /**
     * For all repositories, combine fluxes that run the same query.
     * Subscribe to each flux immediately to get the query started.
     * Add all fluxes to a container flux that processes the results
     * upon completion.
     * After everything is set up, block until completion.
     */
    public void doQuery() {
        final Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.fromIterable(repositories)
                .flatMap(repo -> repo.findAll(example1.get()));
        flux1.subscribe();

        final Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.fromIterable(repositories)
                .flatMap(repo -> repo.findAll(example2.get()));
        flux2.subscribe();

        final Flux<String> flux3 = Flux.fromIterable(repositories)
                .flatMap(repo -> repo.findAll(example3.get()));
        flux3.subscribe();

        final Flux<String> flux4 = Flux.fromIterable(repositories)
                .flatMap(repo -> repo.findAll(example4.get()));
        flux4.subscribe();

        final Flux<String> flux5 = Flux.fromIterable(repositories)
                .flatMap(repo -> repo.findAll(example5.get()));
        flux5.subscribe();

        final Flux<Flux<String>> fluxes = Flux.just(flux1, flux2, flux3, flux4, flux5)
                .doOnComplete(() -> processFluxes(flux1, flux2, flux3, flux4, flux5));
        fluxes.blockLast();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do using Mono.zip:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux<String> flux0 = Flux.empty();
        Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.just("1.1", "1.2", "1.3");
        Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.just("2.1", "2.2", "2.3");
        Flux<String> flux3 = Flux.just("3.1", "3.2", "3.3");
        
        Mono.zip(lists -> process(lists), flux0.collectList(), flux1.collectList(), flux2.collectList(), flux3.collectList()).block();
    }
    
    private static String process(Object[] lists) {
        System.out.println("List 0 is " + lists[0]);
        System.out.println("List 1 is " + lists[1]);
        System.out.println("List 2 is " + lists[2]);
        System.out.println("List 3 is " + lists[3]);
        return "output";
    }
```

which outputs:

```
List 0 is []
List 1 is [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
List 2 is [2.1, 2.2, 2.3]
List 3 is [3.1, 3.2, 3.3]
```

So you can adapt it to your situation.

Note that Mono.zip cannot return null, that's why I put "output" as a result, but if you don't need any output you can put whatever you want which is not null.

The idea is first to convert every `Flux<String>` into `Mono<List<String>>` by using `collectList`, it will be simpler then to process. `Mono.zip` allows you to wait for all to be done, and process the output as `Object[]`. You can convert each object into a `List<String>` for processing.

Comment: This is close to what I need, but I need to be able to differentiate between the lists.  If I would have lists that all contained the same type of object, then the Object[] would work, but I will have different parameterized types.

Comment: I'm not sure to well understand. Here in Object[], each Object correspond to the result of one single Flux, in the same order as you give them in the method zip(), that's why it is just Object because each Flux may have a different type. So you can differentiate them by the order, and cast the Object in the corresponding type. On the example, the output shows that each Object is actually itself a List (of String in my example). Or may be I didn't understand well your point

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood you.  I now see a little better about what you're doing.  But it looks like they are combined after each input produces *a* value.  I need to be able to process everything after it has all finished.

Comment: JavaDoc of zip method: `Aggregate given monos into a new Mono that will be fulfilled when all of the given Monos have produced an item, aggregating their values according to the provided combinator function.` So the process method is called once all have produced an item. Because I used `collectList` on each Flux, it will produce a List once the Flux has finished. So at the end the process method is called when all have finished.

Comment: Hi, Zinc.  I was just reading the javadoc that you mentioned, and I see that the conversion from Flux to Mono means that the fluxes were completed, and the "emission of an item" is the completed result of the Flux.  So thank you for your help and your patience!